# How to pull data from Firebase's firestore into react native app reliably

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am pretty new to development in general, so if I leave out any info that would have helped I apologize. I am building a react-native application using google's Firestore service. I was able to get authentication working reliably and I have data stored in firestore already that is tied to the localId created by Firebase's authentication tool. After the user logs in, they are redirect to the dashboard that will eventually pull stats for the user. However, upon logging in initially, my "dashboard" variable is returning undefined. If I simply save the application without making any changes, it will then no longer be undefined. I have tried several variations of using promises, switching to async / await, and even using setTimeout, but on initial load "dashboard" is still undefined. I have also tried logging the user on initial login to see if I was making a request to firebase with an undefined variable, but that was also not the case. The users logs 100% of the time. Code is below. Please let me know if any additional information would help.

```
  const [dashboard, setDashboard] = useState()
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserDashboard = () => {
      console.log(user);
      dbh
        .collection(`users`)
        .doc(user)
        .get()
        .then((doc) => {
          setDashboard(doc.data());
        })
        .then(() => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(dashboard.userName);
          }, 1000);
        });
    };
    fetchUserDashboard();
  }, []);
```

At @Doug Stevenson's request, I changed the code to the following, and upon initial load, dashboard is still undefined.

```
const [dashboard, setDashboard] = useState(null)
useEffect(() => {
const fetchUserDashboard = () => {
  console.log(user);
  dbh
    .collection(`users`)
    .doc(user)
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
      setDashboard(doc.data());
      console.log(dashboard);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log('Error getting documents: ', error);
    });
};
fetchUserDashboard();
 }, []);
```

The error message simply states:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'dashboard.userName')
```

Comment: This code isn't doing any error handling on promise returned by `get()`.  It could be failing and you'd never know.  Please check for errors, then edit the question with the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `setDashboard`, that triggers your component to be re-rendered in the very near future.  It will not cause `dashboard` to contain a new value immediately.  The value of `dashboard` doesn't change for the duration of its scope where its value was assigned.  You must wait until the next time the component renders to see the new value from the `useState` hook.

If you want to log the results of the Firestore query immediately, you will have to use the variable that contains the results:

```
    .then((doc) => {
      setDashboard(doc.data());
      console.log(doc.data());
    })
```

Comment: I really appreciate you clarifying that for me. I added a ternary operator to show an activity indicator if dashboard is anything but true and I seem to be able to interact with the data now. Thanks so much!